# Is there any analytical solution for minimizing $\|K - Q\|_F^2$ subject to $0 \preceq K \preceq R$?

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization, matrix-decomposition

Let $\|\cdot \|_F$ be Frobenius norm and $\preceq$ be Loewner order. Suppose $K, Q, R$ are $n \times n$ real symmetric matrices. I am curious about the minimizer of $\arg \min_K \|K - Q\|_F^2$ subject to $0 \preceq K \preceq R$.

The motivation for this question is to consider the projection of $Q$ on $\mathcal{D} = \{K : 0 \preceq K \preceq R\}$. Since $\mathcal{D}$ is a closed convex set, there exists a unique projector for this problem.

This problem will become easy if both $Q$ and $R$ share the same eigenbasis. Suppose $Q = U \Lambda U^T$ and $R = U \Sigma U^T$, where $U$ is orthogonal. Then $K^* = U \text{Diag}(\phi(\lambda_1), \dots, \phi(\lambda_n)) U^T$, where $\phi(\lambda_i) = \min\{\lambda_i, \sigma_i\}$.

However, is there any natural decomposition for obtaining the analytical solution to this problem when they share different eigenbasis?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an attempt to at least address the case where $Q,R \succ 0$.

Let $J = R^{-1/2}KR^{-1/2}$. We can express your problem as minimizing $\|R^{1/2}JR^{1/2} - Q\|_F$ subject to
$$
0 \preceq R^{1/2}J R^{1/2} \preceq R \iff 0 \preceq J \preceq I.
$$
We can rewrite the objective function with
$$
\|R^{1/2}JR^{1/2} - Q\|_F^2 = \\
\operatorname{Tr}([R^{1/2}JR^{1/2}]^2) - 2 \operatorname{Tr}[R^{1/2}JR^{1/2}Q] = \\
\operatorname{Tr}(R^{1/2}JRJR^{1/2}) - 2 \operatorname{Tr}[R^{1/2}JR^{1/2}Q] =\\
\operatorname{Tr}(JRJR) - 2 \operatorname{Tr}[JR^{1/2}QR^{1/2}] 
= \\ 
\operatorname{Tr}((JR)^2) - 2 \operatorname{Tr}[J\underbrace{[R^{1/2}QR^{1/2}]}_P].
$$
That is, our objective function is $f(J) = \operatorname{Tr}((JR)^2) - 2\operatorname{Tr}(JP)$, where $P = R^{1/2}QR^{1/2}$.

---

From there, we can try calculus. In [numerator layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Numerator-layout_notation), we have
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial J} = 2(RJR - P).
$$
If a global minimizer exists, it (unsurprisingly) must satisfy
$$
RJR - P = 0 \implies RJR = P \implies R^{1/2}JR^{1/2} = R^{-1/2}PR^{-1/2} \implies K = Q.
$$
Otherwise, the minimizer must lie on the boundary of the region.

A symmetric matrix $M$ is on the boundary of $M \preceq I$ iff its largest eigenvalue is exactly $1$. The "directions" orthogonal to this boundary at $M$ are spanned by matrices of the form $xx^T$, where $x$ is an eigenvector of $M$ associated with the eigenvalue $1$. The method of Lagrange multipliers tells us that this direction must be parallel to $\frac{\partial f}{\partial J}$.

This tells us that the solution $J$ must satisfy the following condition: if $x_1,\dots,x_m$ are a complete independent set of eigenvectors of $J$ associated with the eigenvalue $1$, then it must hold that
$$
P - RJR = \sum_{j=1}^m \alpha_j \,x_jx_j^\top
$$
for some coefficients $\alpha_j$. Equivalently, if $V$ is a matrix whose columns span the eigenspaces of $J$ **not** associated with $1$, then
$$
(P - RJR)V = 0 \iff  V^\top(P - RJR)V = 0.
$$
I have a hunch that we can find our minimizer by taking $V$ to be the eigenvectors of $P$ associated with eigenvalues that are smaller than $1$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think applying Lagrangian is a correct direction since we already know the optimizer should be on the boundary. I will try to analyze the eigenspace of $P$ to see whether it works or not.

Comment: However, the real problem is that if there is only one active constraint acts on the optimizer $J^*$, then I can solve it easily. However, the difficult case is that when there is two active constraints act on $J^*$, then I need to consider two Lagrange multipliers.